# How can I dispatch a checkbox click programmatically?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, dispatchevent

I've tried several javascript functions here and there but it seems that none of them worked for me.
What I'm doing is displaying a tower, that has as many stages as the user wishes. This is basically creating HTML tags using Js for every stage and the last one is a checkbox.
The thing I'd like to do is that when I click on a checkbox, all the other ones that are over this one would check programmatically also. So this is what I did:

```
    let event = new Event('click');

    //Here, q is the maximum stage that the user set.

    document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        let readStr = e.target.id;
        if (readStr.startsWith("checkboxFan") && e.isTrusted) {
            for (let r=parseFloat(readStr.substr(-1))+1; r<=q; r++) {
                document.getElementById("checkboxFan"+r).dispatchEvent(event);
            }
        }
    }, false);
```

And it's finding the IDs well and doing what I want, but the dispatchEvent isn't working as expected. In fact, it's not working at all. Also, the "click()" function works but the isTrusted is triggered, which is not what I want because the checkbox has to be clicked by the user.

Any solutions?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've written some code based on your description.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-poevax?file=index.js

```
document.addEventListener(
  "click",
  function(e) {
    let readStr = e.target.id;
    if (readStr.startsWith("checkboxFan") && e.target.checked) {
      for (let r = parseFloat(readStr.substr(-1)) + 1; r <= q; r++) {
        document.getElementById("checkboxFan" + r).checked = true;
      }
    }
  },
  false
);
```

You should check this page.
[Input Checkbox checked Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp)

cheers!

Comment: How couldn't think about this, ahah !
Thank you so much ;)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27447347)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thank you for the advice.  
I'll be more careful next time.